# Powershell 3.0 Enter-PSSession fails randomly, reboot solves it. DCOM error in Event Viewer on target machine

Tags: windows-server-2012, eventviewer, dcom, powershell-v3.0

Using PowerShell's Enter-PSSession (even locally, against the local computer) fails randomly with the following message. Running Windows 2012 Standard with all updates. The error message takes a while to show up.

Command:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MYHOSTNAME
```

Message:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server MYHOSTNAME failed with the following error message : 
The WSMan service could not launch a host process to process the given request.  
Make sure the WSMan provider host server and proxy are properly registered. 
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MYHOSTNAME
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MYHOSTNAME:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Rebooting the server makes it work again, until after less than 24hs, then it starts failing again.

At the exact same second the message is returned, the following is logged in Event Viewer:

```
Source: DistributedCOM
EventID: 10010
Message: The server {9ACF41ED-D457-4CC1-941B-AB02C26E4686} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

Comment: I've already checked out http://blogs.technet.com/b/davguents_blog/archive/2010/12/10/the-case-of-the-psremotingtransportexception.aspx and it does not apply.